# Retrieve two records within the same table and get datediff in one query

Tags: sql-server, datediff

I have this table

```
sessionid | serviceid | requesttimestamp | etc..
```

My aim is to get a serviceid for logging in and logging out which for arguments sake we will say is 2 and 3. So when the two records have a log in and log out then I want to make sure the sessionid is the same and then datediff the timestamp in order to find out how long the user have been logged in. I also want a condition that if the serviceid for logging in exists for one and not exists for logging out then to skip that record in the results. I wondered if there was a magic way to combine this in one query, so far i have

```
Declare @sessionStart DATETIME , @sessionStart2 as DATETIME
set @sessionStart = (select  requesttimestamp from logentry where serviceid=151 and sessionid = '1234')
set @sessionStart2 = (select requesttimestamp from logentry where serviceid=202 and sessionid = '1234')


select datediff(mi, @sessionStart, @sessionStart2 );
```

This brings me back the required result without the null checking, I have been looking into simple case statements but I am attempting to make this into one query if possible. Any pointers in the right direction would be great

Comment: Are you asking for a solution for both database products? The code you posted is valid only for SQL Server. This isn't a simple query if you want it to work for any session id and the answer will be affected by implementation differences between the products, esp by differences on windowing functions

Comment: Yes I am asking for a solution for both and yes I will eventually want it to work for any sessionid (both of which will always be the same and the serviceid for each will never change). Well, If i cannot make it simple then I can at least attempt some type of result. Is there any advice you can give me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kinda confusing explanation there. :) But to rephrase, the way I understand it is you just want the total minutes for each session's logon time. Is your sessionid unique? Also, you've tagged MYSQL and SQL Server, while your syntax is SQL Server.

IE, something like this, then?

```
SELECT L1.sessionid, DATEDIFF(MI, L1.requesttimestamp, L2.requesttimestamp) LOG_TIME_IN_MINUTES
FROM logentry L1
JOIN logentry L2 ON L2.sessionid  = L1.sessionid
WHERE L1.requesttimestamp IS NOT NULL AND L2.requesttimestamp IS NOT NULL
AND L1.serviceid = 2 AND L2.serviceid = 3
```

Comment: wut? :) Kahn the magic man (or lady). Thank you, apologies for the confusing question but you nailed it, exactly what I was looking for. Have some internet points!

Comment: Thanks, and glad to be of help. :)